# TeamCity & MSBuild integration

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

Is there any way to get TeamCity's build numbering to match the publish version (ApplicationRevision) number generated by MSBuild's publish task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can control the build number in TeamCity via a specially formatted message in the build log. This can be output at any stage (e.g. during publish) and will cause the initially assigned build number to change. See [here](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) for more info.

For example, our msbuild has this to output the version as the build number:

```
<Message Text="##teamcity[buildNumber '$(FullVersion)']"/>
```

Comment: Excellent, didn't know that one.